# How to set MyApp as default app in Android API Level 29 and above?

Tags: android, kotlin

it's been like a couple of days trying to set my app as default targeting `Android API` Level 29 and above but I had no luck!!

What I have trying so far:

- Setting Up Permissions in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_ROLE_DIALER" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.PHONE_APP" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER" />
```

- Declaring the intent
- Adding Kolin Code:

```
// Set companion object:
companion object {
    const val REQUESTCODESETDEFAULTDIALER = 1
}


// Check if the app needs legacy support or the new way
// This function is called from another function: checkAndRequestPermissions()
private fun selectRegisterLogic() {

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            registerAsDefaultDialer()

        } 
    

    else {
            registerAsDefaultDialerLegacy()
        }
}

// Set up the new way via launcher
private val setPhoneAppLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Log.d("YourActivity", "Phone app set as default.")
    }

    else {

        Log.d("someresult", result.toString())
        Log.d("mainactivity.setPhoneAppLanucher", "smth happened")
    }
}

// Call launcher in function
private fun registerAsDefaultDialer() {
    Log.d("called", "yess called")

    val telecomManager = getSystemService(TelecomManager::class.java)

    if (packageName != telecomManager.defaultDialerPackage) {
        val intent = Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER)
        intent.putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName)
            setPhoneAppLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
}
```

The thing is when the result is logged out here's what I get: `ActivityResult{resultCode=RESULT_CANCELED, data=null}`